# Java - substring store into separate string variable

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

So I have a string like the following

```
"1: Command(1, 2, 3)"
```

I ultimately want to store 1 2 3 into `String` variables. How can I accomplish this?

The following is a snippet of code that reads an array of strings and attempts to print out the parameters of that string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TableElements.length; i++) {
  if (sadTableElements[i] != null) {
    System.out.println("DEBUG " + sadTableElements[i]);
    Param0 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf("(") + 1, 
                              TableElements[i].indexOf(",")));
    System.out.println(Param0);

    Param1 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf(",") + 2, 
                              TableElements[i].indexOf(",")));
    System.out.println(Param1);

    Param2 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf(",") + 2, 
                              TableElements[i].indexOf(")")));
    System.out.println(Param2);
  }
}
```

I get this output:

> DEBUG 1: Command(1, 2, 3) 1 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   -2

It seems to stop at `System.out.println(Param1);`

Comment: calculate numbers which should be returned by `indexOf` manually - put them into your code and then you will see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexOf() function in Java returns the first index of the matched substring so
indexOf(",") will always return the index of the first "," that it finds in the entire input string.

i.e. indexOf(",") will always return the index of first "," found in the input string. To fetch the Param1 and Param2 , try using the below code instead :

```
    Param0 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf("(") + 1, TableElements[i].indexOf(",")));
    System.out.println(Param0);
    Param1 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf(",") + 2, TableElements[i].lastIndexOf(",")));
    System.out.println(Param1);
    Param2 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].lastIndexOf(",") + 2, TableElements[i].indexOf(")")));
    System.out.println(Param2);
```

lastIndexOf() function returns the last index of the possible match i.e. it will return the index of second matched "," which should give the correct output.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Param1 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf(",") + 2, TableElements[i].indexOf(",")));
```

The `TableElements[i].indexOf(",")` gives you index of the first `,` character, which is lower than index got from `TableElements[i].indexOf(",") + 2`. That's why you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better use regexp for this:

```
java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^\\d+: Command\\((\\d+), (\\d+), (\\d+)\\)").matcher("1: Command(1, 2, 3)");
if (!m.matches()) {
    throw new AssertionError("Your Regex Pattern or Input is bad");
}
System.out.println(m.group(1) + " | " + m.group(2) + " | " + m.group(3));
```

Output here is: `1 | 2 | 3`

**Note:** If you adapt it, re-use the compiled pattern and do not recompile it for every input String

Answer (score 1):

```
 Param1 = Integer.parseInt(TableElements[i].substring(TableElements[i].indexOf(",") + 2, TableElements[i].indexOf(",")));
```

Both indexOf(...) refer to the exact same colon. So you are building a substring going from index+2 to index. You could either use the split(...) function or save the created substring within a new string.